# Redirect http to https angularjs application

Tags: .htaccess

My app is in angular js which is on sub domain like http://app.xyz.com i want to redirect it to https://app.xyz.com here is htaccess which i used to redirect it

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L]
```

When site load first time it's work fine but when i reload then i got page not found error everytime

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect all urls to https.Try this

```
# Redirect all url to https #
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: it redirecting me to https but when i am trying to reload my page then not working and i got page not found error

Comment: Are you using any other redirect rule or any redirect options in cpanel

Comment: No i just use htaccess to force redirect to https not using cpanel for redirecting